# How to move Open Desktops row to the bottom in Windows Task View

Tags: windows-10, user-interface, task-view

After receiving the Windows 10 April update, Windows now displays the row of open desktops at the top of "Task View" (Win + Tab) instead of the bottom as before the update.

I know this is to accommodate the new Timeline feature (which I've disabled). Can I move the "open desktops" to the bottom? If so, how?

### Old position (desired)

[image: Old task view]

### New position

[image: New task view]